# Discord importing python issue

Tags: python, discord.py

I got this error when i try to import the discord module i installed it with pip install discord i am using pip version 10.0.1 and python 3.7

> `import discord
>     File "C:\Users\chino\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
>       from .client import Client, AppInfo, ChannelPermissions
>     File "C:\Users\chino\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 38, in <module>
>       from .state import ConnectionState
>     File "C:\Users\chino\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\state.py", line 36, in <module>
>       from . import utils, compat
>     File "C:\Users\chino\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\compat.py", line 32
>       create_task = asyncio.async
>                                 ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: There are some issues on github regarding this issue. Previously the module didn't work with 3.7, but as it looks like they fixed it. Are you running the latest version of the Discord module?

Comment: i just did pip install discord so i think so?

Answer (score 1):

Discord.py is not compatible with Python 3.7 as stated on their github. They commited a fix but it's not published yet, so you can either downgrade to Python 3.6 or manually change the files as this commit:

https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/commit/096584733e8a8025b13f46fa920e18abe19352c1

Alternatively, if you really need python 3.7, you can use their updated `rewrite` branch, as they recommend, which has this fix already available.

Edit: Discord.py now supports python 3.7, so this should no longer be a problem.